# How to locate an element using AutomationID for desktop application in Karate automation

Tags: windows, automation, karate, desktop

I am trying to locate an element using AutomationId in karate test automation of windows application.
I have tried multiple ways of locating the element with AutomationId, but none worked. please help me with the syntax.

- locate('#110').click()  -- not recognized
- locate('//[@automationid=110]').click()  -- not recognized
- locate('//[@automationid="110"]').click()  -- not recognized
- locate('//*[@automationid=110]').click() -- not recognized

Comment: a lot depends on your application so I think you are on your own here. try to get someone to help or contribute code to karate

Comment: Hi PeterThomas, what should e the syntax ? How to locate element based on AutomationID value. Please help with the syntax.

Comment: the syntax you used (first one) seems to be correct. maybe the application simply does not support it. I can't tell without seeing the app - so you have to solve this n your own. all the best

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Peter Thomas, locate('#110').click() should work but its not working for our application. Instead below format worked for our application
locate('//pane/pane/group{Frame1}/button{Search}').click()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).